# Yii change controllers login redirect page

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii to serve some JSON webservices for a mobile app. I am using the Yii build in authentication system.

I have a specific controller that I setup access rules so only authenticated users can call the controller functions. When the user is NOT logged in, I want to return a custom JSON response instead of re-directing to the default page. Is there is a way to do this without removing the access rules and using "getIsGuest()?" on each controller?

I believe it's cleaner to do use access rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [set the loginUrl for users](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#handling-authorization-result) to point to the JSON response.

If you still want the default [loginUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginUrl-detail), you could redirect to a simple page with some logic that could redirect to either tha JSON response or the actual login page.